# React Navigation 5, CustomDrawer, Can't perform a React state update on context changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

on App.js, im using useContext to check of user logged in to switch active navigation,

Then, on Login screen after successful login, I got error "Can't perform a React state update on LoginScreen" after the context has changed.

I'm pretty sure it comes from Drawer, because when i try to logout and login back, the drawer opened immediately. but i didn't use any useState to handle login or logout, all my async function only used when handling login or logout not in useState.

you can find my sample video here:
https://vimeo.com/user125707637/review/471649007/2c9dd00d1a

you can see on the video, the drawer opened automatically after the error comes out. each time you login back, the drawer was open and need to close manually. Any idea? or it's a bug.. idk

App.js:

```
const App = ({navigation, route}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [loadingVisible, setLoadingVisible] = useState(true);

  const restoreAuth = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await userApi.getUser();
      setUser(response.data);
      onFinishLoad();
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        return onFinishLoad();
      }
      await storage.removeToken();
      setUser(null);
      onFinishLoad();
    }
  };

  const onFinishLoad = async () => {
    const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
    await delay(500);
    setLoadingVisible(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    if (mounted) {
      restoreAuth();
    }

    return () => (mounted = false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <StyleProvider style={getTheme(material)}>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{user, setUser}}>
        <LoadingComponent visible={loadingVisible} />
        <Container>
          <NavigationContainer>
            {user ? <AppDrawerNavigation /> : <AuthNavigation />} // checking context changes 
          </NavigationContainer>
        </Container>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </StyleProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Auth Navigator:

```
const AuthNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={LoginScreen}
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

LoginScreen:

```
const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [loadingVisible, setLoadingVisible] = useState(false);

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().required().label('E-mail'),
    password: Yup.string().required().min(6).label('Password'),
  });

  const handleSubmit = async ({email, password}, actions) => {
    setLoadingVisible(true);

    try {
      const response = await authApi.login(email, password, 'mobile');

      storage.storeToken(response.data.token);

      setUser(response.data.user);
      setLoadingVisible(false);
    } catch (error) {
      const statusCode = error.response.status;
      const errors = error.response.data;
      const fieldErrors = errors?.errors;
      const errorMessage = errors?.message;

      setLoadingVisible(false);

      if (statusCode === 422) {
        for (let field in fieldErrors) {
          actions.setFieldError(field, fieldErrors[field][0]);
        }
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          'Login Failed',
          `${errorMessage}`,
          [{text: 'Ok', onPress: () => console.log('ok')}],
          {cancelable: false},
        );
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <LoadingComponent visible={loadingVisible} />

      <Content padder>

        <View>
          <Form
            initialValues={{
              email: '',
              password: '',
            }}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}>
            <FormField
              name="email"
              placeholder="E-mail"
              keyboardType="email-address"
              autoCorrect={false}
            />
            <FormField
              name="password"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              placeholder="Password"
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
            <SubmitButton title="LOGIN" />
          </Form>

          <View style={{marginTop: 20}}>
            <Text
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                textAlign: 'center',
                textDecorationLine: 'underline',
                marginBottom: 10,
              }}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Register')}>
              Create an account
            </Text>
            <Text
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                textAlign: 'center',
                textDecorationLine: 'underline',
              }}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword')}>
              Forgot Password?
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Drawer Navigator:

```
 const AppDrawerNavigation = () => {

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="HomeStack"
      drawerContentOptions={{
        activeBackgroundColor: colors.primary,
        activeTintColor: colors.light,
      }}
      drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}> // Render my custom Drawer
      <Drawer.Screen
        name="HomeStack"
        component={HomeStackNavigation}
        options={{
          drawerLabel: ({color, focused}) => (
            <Text style={{fontSize: !focused ? 14 : 16, color: color}}>
              Entries
            </Text>
          ),
          drawerIcon: ({color, size, focused}) => (
            <AntDesign
              name="home"
              color={color}
              size={!focused ? size : size + 2}
            />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
```

DrawerContent:

```
export const DrawerContent = (props) => {
  const {user, setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [loadingVisible, setLoadingVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleLogout = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      null,
      'Are you sure to logout?',
      [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
          style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: _logout,
        },
      ],
      {cancelable: false},
    );
  };

//handling logout
  const _logout = async () => {
    props.navigation.closeDrawer();
    setLoadingVisible(true);

    try {
      const response = await authApi.logout();
      await storage.removeToken();
      setUser(null); // set user context to null
      setLoadingVisible(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setLoadingVisible(false);
      Alert.alert(
        'Error',
        'Failed to logout',
        [
          {
            text: 'OK',
            onPress: console.log('ok'),
          },
        ],
        {cancelable: false},
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <LoadingComponent visible={loadingVisible} />
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <View style={styles.drawerContent}>
          <View style={styles.userInfoSection}>
            <View style={{paddingVertical: 20}}>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 28}}>SMART</Text>
              <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>Incident Management System</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <Drawer.Section style={styles.drawerSection}>
            <DrawerItemList {...props} />
          </Drawer.Section>
        </View>
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
      <Drawer.Section style={styles.bottomDrawerSection}>
        <DrawerItem
          icon={({color, size}) => (
            <AntDesign name="logout" color={color} size={size} />
          )}
          label="Sign Out"
          onPress={handleLogout}
        />
      </Drawer.Section>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have your exact issue, did you manage to solve the problem?